# How would I make something happen whenever I get a kill in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to be able to have my LED lights flash green for a few seconds whenever I get a kill and flash red whenever I die. I am able to make my lights flash I just don't know how I'm going to be able to transfer a signal whenever I die/get a kill in the game. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could program a server which receives data from the game. According to the data you could program some LEDs to flash around.
Here is a [link](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Game_State_Integration) to their developer page.
Or you could use 3rd party site libraries which are also listed on their page at the bottom.